# R: Why is c(4,4) a double?

Tags: r, vector, types

To my eye, `c(4,4)` is obviously a vector of integers, but `typeof(c(4,4))` reports that c(4,4) is a double. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is `numeric` and not `integer`.  If we need `integer`, we can use

```
v1 <- c(4L, 4L)
```

Or convert to `integer` with `as.integer`

```
v2 <- as.integer(c(4, 4))
```

and then check the `class`

According to `?numeric`

> numeric is identical to double (and real). It creates a double-precision vector of the specified length with each element equal to 0.

Also in `?integer`

> Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly.

The use of `L` is specified in `?NumericConstants`

> An numeric constant immediately followed by L is regarded as an integer number when possible (and with a warning if it contains a ".").

Comment: And numeric defaults to double?

Comment: @J.Mini i would check the `class(v1)` instead of `typeof`, it is `numeric` class.  Yes, it defaults because `integer` value range is limited

Comment: Excellent. Where is the documentation for using 4L?  I can't find L documented anywhere.

Comment: @J.Mini sorry, i was away.  It is documented in `?NumericConstants`